# Custom jQuery Mobile transition using -webkit-mask

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to make a custom jQuery Mobile transition using the -webkit-mask transition.

Here is how I've set up the animation function:

```
.mask.in
{
    -webkit-mask-position: 0 0;
    -webkit-animation-name:maskInFromRight;
}
.mask.out{
    -webkit-mask-position: -100% 0;
    -webkit-animation-name:maskOutToLeft;
}
.mask.in.reverse{
    -webkit-mask-position: 0 0;
    -webkit-animation-name:maskInFromLeft;
}
.mask.out.reverse{
    -webkit-mask-position: 100% 0;
    -webkit-animation-name:maskOutToRight;
}


@-webkit-keyframes maskInFromRight
{
    0% { -webkit-mask-position:100% 0; }
    100% { -webkit-mask-position:0 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes maskOutToLeft
{
    0% { -webkit-mask-position:0 0; }
    100% { -webkit-mask-position:-100% 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes maskInFromLeft
{
    0% { -webkit-mask-position:-100% 0; }
    100% { -webkit-mask-position:0 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes maskOutFromRight
{
    0% { -webkit-mask-position:0 0; }
    100% { -webkit-mask-position:100% 0; }
}
```

based on the example that they provide:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-customtransitions.html

Right now it's not using the custom animation and the next page is just appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anyone wondering. I've moved away from the Webkit mask and went with a css3 clip transition.

```
.superClip.in,
.superClip.out{
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 350ms;
}

.superClip.in {
        clip: rect(0px, 2048px, 1536px, 0px);
        -webkit-animation-name: superClipInRight;
}
@-webkit-keyframes superClipInRight {
   from { clip: rect(0px, 2048px, 1536px, 2048px); }
        to { clip: rect(0px, 2048px, 1536px, 0px); }
}

.superClip.out {
        clip: rect(0px, 0px, 1536px, 0px);
   -webkit-animation-name: superClipOutLeft;
}
@-webkit-keyframes superClipOutLeft {
   from {clip: rect(0px, 2048px, 1536px, 0px); }
    to { clip: rect(0px, 0px, 1536px, 0px); }
}

.superClip.in.reverse {
        clip: rect(0px, 2048px, 1536px, 0px);
        -webkit-animation-name: superClipInRightRev;
}
@-webkit-keyframes superClipInRightRev {
   from { clip: rect(0px, 0px, 1536px, 0px); }
        to { clip: rect(0px, 2048px, 1536px, 0px); }
}

.superClip.out.reverse {
        clip: rect(0px, 2048px, 1536px, 2048px);
   -webkit-animation-name: superClipOutLeftRev;
}
@-webkit-keyframes superClipOutLeftRev {
   from {clip: rect(0px, 2048px, 1536px, 0px); }
    to { clip: rect(0px, 2048px, 1536px, 2048px); }
}
```